# golang, архитектура приложения

Tags: golang, архитектура, интерфейс, golang-faq

У меня есть две сущности. Пользователи и заказы.
Я реализовал следующим образом.

```
type UserRepository interface {
    GetUserByID(int) (*models.User, error)
    Create(*models.User) error
    UpdateBalance(int, int, int) error
}

type OrderRepository interface {
    GetOrderByID(int) (*models.Order, error)
    CreateOrder(*models.Order) error
}

type Store interface {
    User() UserRepository
    Order() OrderRepository
}
```

а структура Store выглядит следующим образом:

```
type Store struct {
    db        *sql.DB
    userRepo  *UserRepository
    orderRepo *OrderRepository
}
```

Теперь логика приложения. Я не могу оформить заказ если баланс у пользователя меньше определенной величины. Это меня толкает создать уже service структуру таким образом:

```
type Service struct {
    store store.Store
}

func NewService(store store.Store) ServicesInterface {
    return &Service{
        store: store,
    }
}
```

И в нем уже описать всю логику в том числе создание заказа.
Получается, что в Store interface я должен добавить Service interface, чтобы все выглядело логично... Но я думаю, что все это никак не соответствует нормальной архитектуре.
Как правильно в данном случае построить ?

Answer (score 0):

Довольно сложно, сказать как правильно безДа, в данном случае вы действительно можете рассмотреть вариант добавления Service интерфейса в Store интерфейс. Это позволит собрать все функциональности, связанные с бизнес-логикой, в одном месте.

Однако, вам также стоит рассмотреть вариант создания отдельной структуры Service с соответствующим интерфейсом, которая будет использовать Store интерфейс для доступа к данным и реализации бизнес-логики. Такой подход позволит лучше разделить ответственности и сделает вашу структуру более гибкой.

Примерно так:

```
type Service interface {
    CreateOrder(userID int, amount int) error
}

type ServiceStruct struct {
    store Store
}

func NewService(store Store) Service {
    return &ServiceStruct{store: store}
}

func (s *ServiceStruct) CreateOrder(userID int, amount int) error {
    user, err := s.store.User().GetUserByID(userID)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if user.Balance < amount {
        return fmt.Errorf("insufficient balance")
    }
    err = s.store.User().UpdateBalance(userID, -amount, user.Version)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    order := &models.Order{
        UserID: userID,
        Amount: amount,
    }
    return s.store.Order().CreateOrder(order)
}
```

Этот подход также позволит лучше тестировать реализацию бизнес-логики, так как вы сможете передавать заглушенные (mock) реализации Store интерфейса в Service структуру.

Например:

```
type mockStore struct {
    userRepo  *mockUserRepo
    orderRepo *mockOrderRepo
}

func (m *mockStore) User() UserRepository {
    return m.userRepo
}

func (m *mockStore) Order() OrderRepository {
    return m.orderRepo
}

func TestCreateOrder(t *testing.T) {
    store := &mockStore{
        userRepo: &mockUserRepo{
            users: map[int]*models.User{
                1: {ID: 1, Balance: 100},
            },
        },
        orderRepo: &mockOrderRepo{},
    }
    service := NewService(store)
    err := service.CreateOrder(1, 50)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    user, err := store.User().GetUserByID(1)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, 50, user.Balance)
}
```

Вы можете также рассмотреть вариант создания отдельной структуры `Application`, которая будет содержать в себе `Store` и `Service` структуры и реализовывать соответствующий интерфейс. Это позволит еще лучше разделить ответственности и упростить тестирование.